# Is it acceptable to say "to accuse for doing something"?

Tags: prepositions

Is it right to say "She accused him for breaking her glasses" or we should always use the preposition "of"(She accused him of breaking her glasses")/Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** correct to use "accuse" with "for". **The preposition "of" must be used at all times:**

1. *The surgeon was accused **of** negligence.*
2. *Are you accusing me **of** lying?*